# convert a date string to utc timezone in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, date

My input is `"20220212"` and I should get output like `"2022-02-12T00:00:00+00:00"`

I have written the following code in PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_utc_timestamp, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, date_format, coalesce
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TimestampConversion").getOrCreate()
data = [("2022-02-12",), ("2022/04/11",), ("2022.03.10",)]
columns = ["date_string"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df_result = df.withColumn(
     "formatted_timestamp",
     date_format(
         coalesce(
             from_utc_timestamp(
                 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date_string"), "yyyy-MM-dd")), "UTC"
             ),
             from_utc_timestamp(
                 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date_string"), "yyyy/MM/dd")), "UTC"
             ),
            from_utc_timestamp(
                 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date_string"), "yyyy.MM.dd")), "UTC"
             )
         ),
         "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
     )
)
 df_result.show(truncate=False)
```

What i need is I'm using 3 built-in-function, but I don't want this much built-in functions. Is it possible to write the same code with 2 built-in functions and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it with less built-ins:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp, date_format, coalesce

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TimestampConversion").getOrCreate()

data = [("2022-02-12",), ("2022/04/11",), ("2022.03.10",)]
columns = ["date_string"]
formats = ["yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy.MM.dd", "yyyyMMdd"]

def to_timestamp_with_formats(col, formats):
    return coalesce(*[to_timestamp(col, fmt) for fmt in formats])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df_result = df.withColumn("formatted_timestamp", to_timestamp_with_formats(col("date_string"), formats))
df_formatted = df_timestamp.withColumn("formatted_timestamp", date_format(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"))
df_formatted.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: its showing system local time 2022-02-12T00:00:00+05:30 but i want 2022-02-12T00:00:00+00:00. may i know why its taking default time and how to rectify this...??

Comment: Sure, you can specify a timezone, for example `timezone = "America/New_York"` and then adjust the return of the function to convert to timestamp like this `return coalesce(*[to_timestamp(col, fmt).withTimeZone(timezone) for fmt in formats])`